# check that a specific user has specific permission in lightswitch

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm using lightswitch in VB , i need to check is a given user has specific permission ("User") or not 
I've tried the below code:

```
        Dim myper = Me.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.Permissions.Where(Function(p) p.Id.Equals("LightSwitchApplication:User", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault


        If Not myper Is Nothing Then
            Dim myu = myper.RolePermissions.SelectMany(Function(u) u.Role.RoleAssignments).Select(Function(us) us.UserName = UserName)
            If Not myu Is Nothing Then
                ' this mean no user has the user permission!
                results.AddPropertyError("found")
            Else
                'user has been found for this permission 
                results.AddPropertyError("not found")
            End If
        Else
            'this mean no roles has this permission !

        End If
```

but unfortunately the myu object always return nothing i don't know why, sorry for that but I'm new in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Application.User object for this.

In csharp:

```
if(this.Application.User.HasPermission(Permissions.PermXYZ))
{
    //permitted
}
```

Comment: your code is checking the logged in user , but here i need to check the given username string.